# Запятая перед "какой"

Tags: пунктуация

Как здесь правильно расставить знаки препинания? Нужна ли запятая перед словом "какой", и всегда ли она в таких конструкциях ставится?

> А ты сам-то какой!..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**А ты сам-то какой!** Запятая не нужна. Например: А ты сам-то какой трус!

**Из словаря:** КАКОЙ,  местоим. прил. 3. **(в восклиц. предл.).** Употр. для выражения эмоциональной оценки говорящим какого-л. явления, действия, субъекта (удивление, негодование, восхищение и т.п.). Какой же ты трус!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна: *А ты сам-то какой!..* Здесь *какой* — местоимение, служащее для выражение сильной эмоциональной окраски.

Запятая перед *какой* ставится, когда оно присоединяет придаточное предложение (т. е. когда стоит на границе двух грамматических основ), например: *Я даже не знал, какой он хороший друг!* Здесь *какой* находится между грамматическими основами *я не знал* и *он друг*, поэтому запятая ставится.